# How to Track any specific object that we want in an image?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, object-detection, tracking

I want to track any object that I want in a video frame without any object detection algorithm like haar-cascade, faster-RCNN, SSD or YOLO. 
How can I do this? Please, recommend me any method.

I used OpenCV Tracking API as Adrian's indicated here https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/06/tracking-multiple-objects-with-opencv/

But, I wanna make more complex tracker. 
Can developers recommend me any algorithm or other APIs ?

Comment: You seem to want a lot of things without applying any effort. [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm that you mentioned are probably the best choice. 
By the way, if you have some images of the object you want to find, you can try to use

> SIFT points (a.k.a. SURF points in Matlab)

and write yourself a detector.

You could find some problem with the scaling factor and probably computational time, but i think you could try with this technique.

Comment: Thank you for your answering for my question. Actually, I want to track any object. So, I don't have image that I want to detect it. I want to track any object, when the video is playing or a camera is running.

Comment: @mmtaksuu i don't think that is possible. You should search for unsupervised object detection, but is not that easy and certainly there are no "accomplished" algorithm like the one you mentioned before. 

Only thing i can say is that you could try with a lot of negative example and some data augmentation, but you'll need at least one positive example ( you could get it by cropping your video i think).

Comment: I really thank you for your help. I agree with you. I will try to crop an object from a video frame without stopping. After that I will train it for a while, then detect and track it. I will reply you about the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import copy

class selectROI():

    def __init__(self):
        self.refPt = []
        self.clickEventsEnabled = False
        self.drawingRectangle = False
        self.rectangleDrawn = False
        self.x_start = -1
        self.y_start = -1
        self.ref_frame = None

    def clickPolygonPoints(self, event, x, y, flags, param):

        temp_frame = self.ref_frame.copy()

        if(self.clickEventsEnabled == True):
                if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
                        if((self.rectangleDrawn == False)):
                            self.drawingRectangle = True
                            self.x_start,self.y_start = x,y
                            self.refPt.append((x,y))

                elif event ==  cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE: 
                        if(self.drawingRectangle == True):
                            cv2.rectangle(temp_frame, (self.x_start,self.y_start), (x,y), (0,0,255), 2)
                            cv2.imshow("ref_frame", temp_frame)
                            temp_frame = self.ref_frame

                elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
                        if((self.rectangleDrawn == False)):
                            self.drawingRectangle = False
                            self.rectangleDrawn = True
                            cv2.rectangle(self.ref_frame, (self.x_start, self.y_start), (x,y), (0,0,255), 2)
                            self.refPt.append((self.x_start, self.y_start))
                            self.refPt.append((x, self.y_start))
                            self.refPt.append((x, y))
                            self.refPt.append((self.x_start, y))

                            roiPoints = [(self.x_start, self.y_start), (x, y)]

                            if len(roiPoints) == 2: #when two points were found
                                    roi = self.ref_frame[roiPoints[0][1]:roiPoints[1][1], roiPoints[0][0]:roiPoints[1][0]]
                                    cv2.imshow("Cropped", roi)


    def maskImg_WithROI(self, frame, ROIPointsList):
            pointsArray = np.array(ROIPointsList)
            mask = np.zeros(frame.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
            white = (255,255,255)
            cv2.fillPoly(mask, np.int32([pointsArray]), white)
            maskedImage = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, mask)
            return maskedImage  

    def outputROIMask(self, frame, ROIPointsList):
            pointsArray = np.array(ROIPointsList)
            pointsArray = pointsArray.reshape((-1,1,2))
            mask = np.zeros(frame.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
            white = (255,255,255)
            cv2.fillPoly(mask, np.int32([pointsArray]), white)
            return mask  

    def main(self):

            self.clickEventsEnabled = True

            self.ref_frame = cv2.imread('picture.png')
            originalRef_Frame = self.ref_frame.copy()

            cv2.namedWindow("ref_frame")
            cv2.setMouseCallback("ref_frame", self.clickPolygonPoints)

            while True:

                    cv2.imshow("ref_frame", self.ref_frame)

                    key = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF

                    if key == ord("r"):
                         self.ref_frame = originalRef_Frame.copy()
                         self.refPt = []
                         self.drawingRectangle = False
                         self.rectangleDrawn = False
                         self.x_start, self.y_start = -1,-1

                    elif key == ord("p"):
                         self.clickEventsEnabled = False
                         self.ref_frame = originalRef_Frame.copy()
                         self.drawingRectangle = False
                         self.rectangleDrawn = False
                         break

                    elif key == ord("q"):
                            break

            self.ref_frame = self.maskImg_WithROI(self.ref_frame, self.refPt)
            cv2.imshow("ref_frame", self.ref_frame)

            roiMask = self.outputROIMask(self.ref_frame, self.refPt)
            cv2.imwrite("ROI.jpg", roiMask)

            cv2.waitKey(0)
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    selROI = selectROI()
    selROI.main()`
```